# How can I increment a css top value of multiple elements at different times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have been trying to get this functionality to work but has been giving me trouble.

**JsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lm30zcxf/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

    <button>CLICK</button>

    <div class="circle circle-1"></div>
    <div class="circle circle-2"></div>
    <div class="circle circle-3"></div>
    <div class="circle circle-4"></div>
    <div class="circle circle-5"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.circle-1{ top: 10em; left: 10em; }

.circle-2{ top: 20em; left: 20em; }

.circle-3{ top: 30em; left: 30em; }

.circle-4{ top: 40em; left: 40em; }

.circle-5{ top: 50em; left: 50em; }

button{ padding: 10px 50px; display: table; margin: auto; }
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        //move each circle down out of screen one at a time

        //then after about 3 seconds have them appear in the same spot they were initially in
    });
});
```

**My Goal:**

- You click the button
- the first circle drops all the way down where it can't be visible
  anymore, about 1 second apart the circle 2 drops then 1 second later
  circle 3 and so forth until all circles are not visible anymore.
- then about 3 seconds after every circle has dropped they appear again
  in the same exact position they originally started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will get you started. By using index in loop can increment animation delay

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var top =$(window).height(),// amount to offset
        $circles = $('.circle'),
        numCircles = $circles.length;

    $circles.each(function(i, elem){
        var $circ = $(this);
        // store intial start point
        $circ.data('top', $circ.position().top);
        // increment delay for drop
        $circ.delay(i*1000).animate({top:top}, function(){
            // increment delay to return
            $circ.delay( (i+numCircles) * 1000).animate({top:$circ.data('top')});
        });            
    });           
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm30zcxf/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Great code! very clean with jquery each method. But one question though, can you please explain this part `.position().top);` I understand that position() is a jquery method that grabs the coordinates of the matched element but what is the `.top`

Comment: top is y coordinate of position() .... properties returned are `left` and `top`   http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: switch the math around. You have a total number to work from

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `setTimeout(function(){}, milliseconds)`.

You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: In addition to that he can also apply [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for animation or [jquery's animate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp)